# Confusion in python tutorial example

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found the below example in python tutorial and not able to get it.

when i run:

```
>>> for x in range(1, 11):
    print(repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3), end=' ')


 1   1  2   4  3   9  4  16  5  25  6  36  7  49  8  64  9  81 10 100
```

The output above is in a horizontal line  but when i run the another code i get output in vertical lines without any newline symbol as given below why?

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    print(repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3), end=' ')
    print(repr(x*x*x).rjust(4))



     1   1    1
     2   4    8
     3   9   27
     4  16   64
     5  25  125
     6  36  216
     7  49  343
     8  64  512
     9  81  729
    10 100 1000
```

https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting

Comment: Because you've added an extra `print` call that **doesn't** have `end=' '`?

Comment: jonrsharpe hit the nail on the head.  the default end character is '\n' which is the newline character.  in your first example you are telling it to use a space instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this on [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

If you don't specify the `end` parameter, it uses `'\n'` which is a new line. So every time you call `print(repr(x*x*x).rjust(4))`, it creates a new line. You first `print` call explicitly uses a space at then end of your string while your second call doesn't.

If you want to keep your output on one line, use the `end` parameter in your second call of `print`

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    print(repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3), end=' ')
    print(repr(x*x*x).rjust(4), end=' ')
```

Comment: for x in range(1, 11):
 print(repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3), repr(x*x*x).rjust(4))      this will also print the output in the vertical line right?

Comment: Try it and see. (yes, assuming `xx`  is meant to be `x*x` (or is defined somewhere))